# Docker machine get nginx error 502 Bad Gate

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, typo3, docker-compose

I'am using `TYPO3` `Docker` Boilerplate and `dinghy`. The thing is that when i access from my local machine the `typo3.docker` i get `502 Bad Gate nginx/1.13.5`, i didn't choose to install `nginx`, but `apache`.

Have anyone any ideas about why i get this `nginx` error ?

**Dockerfile.development**

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-14.04

ENV PROVISION_CONTEXT "development"

# Deploy scripts/configurations
COPY etc/             /opt/docker/etc/

RUN ln -sf /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab /etc/cron.d/docker-boilerplate \
    && chmod 0644 /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab \
    && echo >> /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab \
    && ln -sf /opt/docker/etc/php/development.ini /opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini

# Configure volume/workdir
WORKDIR /app/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
      ...
      environment:
         - VIRTUAL_HOST=.typo3.docker
         - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
         - POSTFIX_RELAYHOST=[mail]:1025

...
```

Comment: i've found that error provide from `nginx-proxy`

Comment: SOLVED: the docker container was located to `/var/www/` and the issue was about `permissions`. I moved the docker container to `~/` and it works fine